# How do I find the http root directory of a remote server (via FTP)?

Tags: php, ftp

Basically if you have a list of documents like /httpdocs,/hdocs
How would you find the root directory of the remote server?

I found a way to do this for a local server..

```
$docRoot = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
```

would it work if I upload this script to the remote server, execute it, and just request the output back?

Comment: I dont think pure FTP can give you this information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$docRoot = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

or left yours exapmle without changes. Read official [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php).

Answer (score 0):

Save this to a PHP file and upload it to the remote server, then run this page from a browser.

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Show just the module information.
// phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>
```

Here is a reference for you:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use [getcwd()](http://in.php.net/getcwd)

```
 <?php

// current directory
echo getcwd() . "\n";

chdir('cvs');

// current directory
echo getcwd() . "\n";

?>
```

with this you will get the abosolute path. From the absolute path you can extract the root directory.

**output:**

```
/home/didou
/home/didou/cvs
```